# How do I troubleshoot my outdoor porch light?

Tags: electrical, outdoor, light

My outdoor porch light will not work after a storm.  Every other light and plug all came back on but this one light won’t work.  Replaced the bulbs still nothing.  My voltage pen doesn’t go off when testing the light and switch.

How do I troubleshoot this fixture?

Comment: "Came back on"? There was a power outage? Brought on by a storm?

Comment: Look for a GFCI, somewhere (not always sensible in relation to the protected device) that's in need of resetting.

Comment: Might be obvious, but it's unmentioned: have you checked the breaker box?